# how to configure Device for boot loader installation

Tags: partitioning

As I am new to Ubuntu/Linux I'm not sure how best to configure the following:
Can someone please point me in the right direction? eg what to delete, keep, and/or change?

Regards Baz

```
/dev/sda
free space      1 MB
/dev/sda1 efi   272 MB   68MB Windows boot manager
/dev/sda2       16 MB    UNKNOWN
/dev/sda3 ntfs  999393 MB 0 MB
/dev/sda4 ntfs  513 MB   446MB
free space      7 MB
```

Comment: From live installer and terminal post this above: `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL | egrep -v "^loop"` Usually just shrink largest NTFS partition with Windows. Make sure Windows fast start up is off, so NTFS partitions can be seen. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi